# Why do house geckos take so long to react?

Tags: zoology, electrophysiology, herpetology

[image: gecko]
This is the [Common house gecko](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_house_gecko) found abundantly where I live.

I've been observing this for quite long and I used to ignore it after thinking on it for a short while. Today I decided to write this here on Biology SE.

So in my lawn there's this large wall on which there are usually around 3-4 geckos foraging for their favorite insects in night. Everytime I walk towards them some of them instantly go into their hiding spots (within 1-2 seconds of my arrival) with lightening speed. But **most** of them initially look cool and not actually bothered by my presence. Not only that -I can even wave at them; go closer towards them and nothing happens. But suddenly after all of my actions they also run towards their hidings as they were daydreaming. (Though not instantly)

Just curious-

**Is there any real lag between their signal reception and processing?**

**Are there some other animals which show such behavioural responses?**

(Maybe they are just kidding with me :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is entirely behavioral and is quite widespread.**

If they ran away everything something large passed by they would waste a lot of energy, many animals wait first to see if you are just moving through, and thus can be ignored, OR if you are going to hang around and thus are a potential threat (and in the case of camouflaged organisms have a much higher chance of spotting them).

It is seen in many animals [gazelle](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003347283710596) are known for it for instance.  [This](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003347209003601) paper on the behavior in other lizards should help with understanding the evolutionary pressures behind it.